# migrated project from xcode 8 to xcode 9 crash on launcher screen

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9

Everything was working fine on xcode 7.3.1, Than I have to add braintree 3ds sdk which is supported on xcode 8. So, I migrated the code to xcode 8 and than xcode 9. Now, build working fine on below IOS 11 but on ios 11 and above app is crashing before opening new main screen. I am new to Ios please help.

it's crashing on this line :

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KbNav") as! KabNavigationController

2018-08-30 12:25:52.730641+0500 Kab[2970:32711] *** Assertion failure in 
-[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight], 
 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit- 
 3698.33.6/_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS.m:569
 2018-08-30 12:25:52.769549+0500 Kab[2970:32711] *** Terminating app due 
 to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. 
 Contentview size is zero.'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115da712b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000114d50f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115dac2f2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x00000001147f1d69 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x00000001131382f5 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight] + 265
5   UIKit                               0x0000000112eb65e0 -[UINavigationItem _desiredHeightForBarMetrics:defaultHeightBlock:] + 90
6   UIKit                               0x000000011313afa1 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS heightRangeFittingWidth:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x000000011264a0ed -[UINavigationBar _heightRangeForNavigationItem:fittingWidth:] + 210
8   UIKit                               0x0000000112726a98 -[UINavigationController _intrinsicNavigationBarHeightRangeForViewController:] + 187
9   UIKit                               0x00000001127269b6 -[UINavigationController _preferredHeightForHidingNavigationBarForViewController:] + 628
10  UIKit                               0x000000011271688f -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:] + 356
11  UIKit                               0x0000000112716cf8 -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:] + 388
12  UIKit                               0x000000011271e555 -[UINavigationController loadView] + 243
13  UIKit                               0x00000001126e105c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
14  UIKit                               0x00000001126e18b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
15  Kab                           0x000000010f00faea -[SlideNavigationController setEnableShadow:] + 74
16  Kab                           0x000000010f00d494 -[SlideNavigationController setup] + 244
17  Kab                            0x000000010f00d1d1 -[SlideNavigationController initWithCoder:] + 145
18  Kab                            0x000000010f20e1d6 _T08Kab0A20NavigationControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfc + 214
19  Kab                           0x000000010f20e29f _T08Kab0A20NavigationControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfcTo + 47
20  UIKit                               0x00000001129ca4c8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
21  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
22  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1ee3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
23  UIKit                               0x000000011264675a -[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 753
24  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
25  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1ee3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
26  UIKit                               0x0000000112eb15f2 -[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 1018
27  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
28  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1ee3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
29  UIKit                               0x00000001126dc053 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 432
30  Kab                           0x000000010f29a6a8 _T08Kab18HomeViewControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfc + 7704
31  Kab                           0x000000010f29a77f _T08Kab18HomeViewControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfcTo + 47
32  UIKit                               0x00000001129ca4c8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
33  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
34  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1ee3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
35  UIKit                               0x00000001129ca194 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
36  UIKit                               0x00000001129ca8d0 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 59
37  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
38  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1f2a7 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
39  UIKit                               0x0000000112c1ee3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
40  UIKit                               0x00000001129c9391 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
41  UIKit                               0x0000000112e59fc2 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
42  Kab                          0x000000010f135a7b _T08Kabr24LaunchTourViewControllerC4skipyyXlF + 219
43  Kab                           0x000000010f136118 _T08Kab24LaunchTourViewControllerC4skipyyXlFTo + 56
44  UIKit                               0x000000011253a972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
45  UIKit                               0x00000001126b9c3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
46  UIKit                               0x00000001126b9f59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
47  UIKit                               0x00000001126b8e86 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
48  UIKit                               0x00000001125b0807 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
49  UIKit                               0x00000001125b1f2a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
50  UIKit                               0x0000000112555365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
51  UIKit                               0x0000000112ea1a1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
52  UIKit                               0x0000000112ea4672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
53  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115d4a101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
54  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115de9f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
55  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115d2ea19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
56  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115d2dfff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
57  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115d2d889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
58  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000118d049c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
59  UIKit                               0x00000001125395d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
60  Kab                           0x000000010f191137 main + 55
61  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000117112d81 start + 1
62  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
  )
       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**KbNavigationController**

```
class KabNavigationController: SlideNavigationController {

var menuItems: [(id: String, image: String, text: String)] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.leftMenu = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController")

    navigationBar.barTintColor = Theme.DarkGray
    navigationBar.tintColor = Theme.White
    navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black

    // Popup Navigation Bar
    STPopupNavigationBar.appearance().isHidden = true

}

}
```

Comment: The issue seems inside `KabNavigationController` code (`Contentview size is zero`).  Share `KabNavigationController ` code

Comment: check the updated question.

Comment: There are few other dependencies, would recommend to put a `debugger` and debug. OR debug by commenting and running code if not comfortable with debugger. Also, don't forget to add `super. viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I have added super.viewDidLoad() to KBNavController.

Comment: debugger stops on this line :  `let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KbNav") as! KabNavigationController`

Comment: It is crashing because of `as!` as `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KbNav")` must be returning return `nil`. Basically, there is some issue in the initialization of `KabNavigationController `

Comment: its working fine below ios 11 versions phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and debug my code alot keep in mind always enable exception break points to trigger exactly which line causing the crash. You can learn it from this [Exception Breakpoint in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode/17802868#17802868) . I found my solution here https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu/issues/250.

move these two lines from setup function to viewWillLayoutSubviews of Slide Menu.

```
//moved this from the `setup` function: 
self.enableShadow = YES;
self.enableSwipeGesture = YES;
```